# Why is my OpenMP code experiencing high latency in production despite performing well in development environment?

Tags: performance, openmp, low-latency

Below is a parallel task model using omp.
The proc1, ..., proc4 each costs below 1ms to finish. And in develop environment(2 physical CPU, 16 core in total) the job finishes perfectly.

But in production environment(same machine, about half core is full throttle 100% in use), the code runs into big latency trouble taking more than 10ms or so constantly.

It is definitly not a occasional phenomenon as the main program calls this code 100x times and everytime it takes more than 10ms to finish.

```c
    const size_t ALIGNMENT = 8; // Align to 8 bytes
    const size_t SIZE = num_feature * sizeof(union Entry);
    union Entry* inst = aligned_alloc(ALIGNMENT, SIZE);
    memset(inst, 0, SIZE); // Clear memory
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    #pragma omp parallel 
    {
        /* init timer */
        #pragma omp single
        {
            #pragma omp task
            score1 = proc1(inst, 0); /* proc1 timer */
            #pragma omp task
            score2 = proc2(inst, 0); /* proc2 timer */
            #pragma omp task
            score3 = proc3(inst, 0); /* proc3 timer */
            #pragma omp task
            score4 = proc4(inst, 0); /* proc4 timer */
        }
    } /* hanging for no reason?
    free(inst);
    /* total timer */
```

I did thorough logging and it shows me that the proc1, ..., proc4 finished on time using 1ms each, but the program hangs at the end of parallel region and maybe having trouble for the threads syncing at the barrier.

Many many thanks, I am in total lost but to use the old sequential computing... here is some logging,

in production environment:

```
  init time(ms): 0.016000    
  init from thread 0, pid 1038162, thread id 139639529867008, cpu 4
  proc1 from thread 3, pid 1038162, thread id 139638764283648, cpu 12
  proc2 from thread 4, pid 1038162, thread id 139638755890944, cpu 14
  proc3 from thread 2, pid 1038162, thread id 139638772676352, cpu 13
  proc4 from thread 15, pid 1038162, thread id 139637775398656, cpu 2
  proc4 time(ms): 0.383000
  proc3 time(ms): 0.501000
  proc2 time(ms): 0.513000
  proc1 time(ms): 0.582000
  total time(ms): 11.867000
```

in develop environment:

```
  inst time(ms): 0.004000
  init from thread 0, pid 1059897, tid 140013452008448, cpu 5
  proc1 from thread 2, pid 1059897, tid 140013211875072, cpu 3
  proc2 from thread 3, pid 1059897, tid 140013203482368, cpu 0
  proc4 from thread 0, pid 1059897, tid 140013452008448, cpu 5
  proc3 from thread 1, pid 1059897, tid 140013220267776, cpu 10
  proc4 time(ms): 0.095000
  proc3 time(ms): 0.107000
  proc2 time(ms): 0.115000
  proc1 time(ms): 0.112000
  total time(ms): 0.163000
```

Comment: Same compiler in both environments?

Comment: yes. same binary and compiler.

Comment: And what happens in serial mode (compilation without OpenMP) ?

Comment: in serial mode, the time would be exactly the sum of procN. I am thinking whether there is something wrong the the #pragma omp single barrier and the outter loop barrier. there would be two barriers. But this cannot explain why the dev environment works fine. Maybe the worsen cpu loads would drastically slow down the barrier sync?

Comment: Did you test the serial version, or do you just assume? Sometimes when tracking weird bugs or issues, it's a good thing to eliminate even unlikely hypothesis.

Comment: Also, insert a timer just after the `single` contruct to see if some threads are stuck somewhere. Try a `nowait`clause in the `single` directive. And add another timer just before the `free`

Comment: sure. I also did the pthread_create parallel version. I changed to omp version cuz I want to reduce the thread create and destroy overhead...

Comment: yes. I intended to try the single no wait version tomorrow in production. thanks bro.

Comment: Not a solution to this issue, but this code is a natural candidate for OpenMP sections rather than tasks. You could give a try.

Comment: OK, honestly I am not a pro on OpenMP and I talked with chatgpt for a while. Then. LoL. I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: What compiler and compiler options do you use? How do you determine the total time and proc time?